# How to get all the link present in the div tag using Goutte

Tags: php, laravel-5, goutte

I am trying to get the all links present inside the div tag.
I am able to get all the name but also wants to get the links also.
Sample Html:

```
<li id="u_1y_y" class="friendBrowserListUnit">
<div class="clearfix">
<a class="_8o _8t lfloat _ohe" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" href="/profile.php?id=100004732455685&fref=pymk" role="presentation">
<div class="clearfix _42ef">
<div class="rfloat _ohf">
<div class="friendBrowserContentAlignMiddle">
<div class="friendBrowserNameTitle fsl fwb fcb">
<a href="/profile.php?id=100004732455685&hc_location=friend_browser&fref=pymk">Jeya Kumar</a>
</div>
<div class="friendBrowserMarginTopMini"></div>
<div class="fsm fwn fcg">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li id="u_1y_y" class="friendBrowserListUnit">
<div class="clearfix">
<a class="_8o _8t lfloat _ohe" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" href="/profile.php?id=100004732455&fref=pymk" role="presentation">
<div class="clearfix _42ef">
<div class="rfloat _ohf">
<div class="friendBrowserContentAlignMiddle">
<div class="friendBrowserNameTitle fsl fwb fcb">
<a href="/profile.php?id=100004732&hc_location=friend_browser&fref=pymk">Aman Kumar</a>
</div>
<div class="friendBrowserMarginTopMini"></div>
<div class="fsm fwn fcg">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

What I tried:

```
$message = $crawler->filter('div.friendBrowserNameTitle.fsl.fwb.fcb');
foreach ($message as $key) {
    echo $key->textContent . '<br>';
}
```

Output:

```
Jeya Kumar
Aman Kumar
```

But how to get the links:

```
/profile.php?id=100004732455685&hc_location=friend_browser&fref=pymk
/profile.php?id=100004732&hc_location=friend_browser&fref=pymk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user makes a request using Goutte, a `Symfony\Component\DomCrawler` instance is returned.  The Crawler object provides the [Crawler::links()](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#links) utility method, providing all links within the given crawler object.

The `Crawler::links()` method will return an array of links found within.

```
$links = $crawler->links();
foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo $link->getUri();
}
```